# AL COMPILAR EN JAVA ME SALE ESTO .java uses unchecked or unsafe operations, Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details

Tags: java, javac

Al compilar el el archivo java con `javac` me sale este mensaje ¿Qué significa y como lo soluciono, no entiendo bien? Gracias

> Note: Practica34.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.

> Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

Uso para compilar el comando `javac` con `OpenJDK 11`.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Practica34 extends JFrame implements ItemListener{

    private JComboBox combo1;

    public Practica34(){

        setLayout(null);
        combo1 = new JComboBox();
        combo1.setBounds(10, 10, 80, 20);
        add(combo1);
    
        combo1.addItem("Rojo");
        combo1.addItem("Verde");
        combo1.addItem("Azul");
        combo1.addItem("Amarillo");
        combo1.addItem("Negro");
        combo1.addItemListener(this);

    }

    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent evento){

        if(evento.getSource() == combo1){
            String seleccion = combo1.getSelectedItem().toString();
            setTitle(seleccion);

        }

    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
    
        Practica34 formulario = new Practica34();
        formulario.setBounds(0, 0, 200, 150);
        formulario.setVisible(true);
        formulario.setResizable(false);
        formulario.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

JComboBox está preparado para usar Generics, puedes ver que la clase está declarada como `JComboBox<T>`
Tú lo estás usando sin declarar el tipo que va a contener, que en tu caso son Strings, y por eso sale el warning

Cambia a

`private JComboBox<String> combo1;`

...

`combo1 = new JComboBox<>();`

Comment: No entendí del todo lo que me indicaste pero voy a copiar tu explicación como comentario en el programa para leerla con mas calma cuando llegue a casa. Gracias.