# Error con ComboBox

Tags: java

estoy haciendo un programa de conversiones básicas, y quise añadir un ComboBox para seleccionar la unidad a convertir

```
    public void JComboBoxProperties(){
        String [] unidades = {"Seleccionar","Octal", "Hexadecimal", "Binario", "Decimal"};
        JComboBox codeP = new JComboBox(unidades);
        codeP.setBounds(20, 60, 100, 20);
        codeP.setSelectedItem("Seleccionar");
        codeP.setVisible(true);
    }
```

pero al ejecutar me manda la siguiente advertencia (PanelC es el nombre de la clase):

```
Note: PanelC.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.

Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

en sí el código corre pero al tratar de obtener el valor de la opción seleccionada con getSelectedItem solo me la la primera opcion, aunque elija otra, y creo que tiene que ver con esa adventencia
no encuentro ningún error al definir las propiedades del ComboBox, pero es específicamente este el que me está dando esa advertencia.

Comment: Muy util ésta respuesta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/448950/al-compilar-en-java-me-sale-esto-java-uses-unchecked-or-unsafe-operations-reco/449009#449009

Comment: muchas gracias, me sirvió!

Answer (score 0):

JComboBox necesita ser parametrizado, de la siguiente manera `JComboBox<E>();`, para que no te salte ese warning. En tu caso tendría que ser `JComboBox<String>(unidades)`

Comment: Gracias!, ya no me aparece el warning :)